# Subfigure space adjustment -- \subfigcapskip and \subfigtopskip

Tags: spacing, floats, subfloats

I want to adjust the space in a *subfigure* environment. Specifically, using `\subfigcapskip` to increase the space between the subfigure and subcaption, and using `\subfigtopskip` to reduce the space on the top of the subfigure, **simultaneously**. I know that I can use either `\subfigcapskip` or `\subfigtopskip` in the following way, but how can I use `\subfigcapskip` and `\subfigtopskip` **simultaneously**?

```
\documentclass[9.5pt,conference,compsocconf,letterpaper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}[htp]{0.5\textwidth}
        {\subfigcapskip = 20pt \subfigure[text A]{\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{a.eps}}}
        \subfigure[text B]{\includegraphics[width=0.47\textwidth]{b.eps}}
        \caption{text C}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please make this into a minimal working example, from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, with the necessary packages for reproducing the issue? If you're using the `subfigure` package, then note that it has been deprecated for more than a decade.

Comment: @egreg A MWE is added. As you said `subfigure` has been deprecated for more than 10 years, then what package should I use to deal with sub-figures?

Comment: @Bloodmoon - You should consider using the `subcaption` package.

Comment: @Mico I see. Any idea about this question? I've been looking around but cannot find anything helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The `subfigure` package is deprecated. With `IEEEtran` you can use `subfig`, with the option `caption=false` that doesn't load the incompatible package `caption`.

I repeat the figure twice, one with the default setting, one with a setting for `farskip` and `nearskip` to show the difference.

Note that the `demo` option for `graphicx` is just not to bother with a real file; the `kantlipsum` package provides mock text.

```
\documentclass[9.5pt,conference,compsocconf,letterpaper]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % demo is just for the example
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % just for the example

\begin{document}

\kant[1]

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\subfloat[text A]{\includegraphics[width=0.47\columnwidth]{a.eps}}\hfill
\subfloat[text B]{\includegraphics[width=0.47\columnwidth]{b.eps}}
\caption{text C}
\end{figure}

\kant[2]

\begin{figure}[htp]
\captionsetup[subfloat]{farskip=0pt,nearskip=0pt}
\centering
\subfloat[text A]{\includegraphics[width=0.47\columnwidth]{a.eps}}\hfill
\subfloat[text B]{\includegraphics[width=0.47\columnwidth]{b.eps}}
\caption{text C}
\end{figure}

\kant

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Since the two subfloats are now separated maximally via `\hfill`, is the `\centering` instruction needed (or useful)?

Comment: @Mico It's handy to have it anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and detailed explanation of the package options. But I want to adjust individually adjust the space of a single sub-figure, e.g., Fig. 2(b) in the above example, rather than a one-fit-all rule. How can I do that?

Comment: @Bloodmoon It's difficult to understand without a more detailed example. Why would you change the parameters for just one subfigure?